# Release older frames stored with AVPlayterItemOutput

Tags: memory, crash, avfoundation, avplayeritem

I have an `AVPlayerItem` used to play a remote HLS stream, and an `AVPlayerItemOutput` object added as an output. As it plays, my phone's wired memory usage goes up and up until I simply get a memory crash. It seems like the output is retaining all of the old frames. However, I only ever want the most recent frame at any moment.

How can I prevent this memory usage issue?

Comment: can you show some code? especially the parts that mention the  `AVPlayerItemOutput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by waiting to add the player output until the video had loaded enough content to play. No idea why that would help!